# Is This sequence unbounded or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to check if $x_n=n(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$ is unbounded or not.

I tried this way. Please, tell me if it is correct or not:

I want to prove that $\forall M>0$, $\exists n>n_0$, such that $x_n > M$. So, let be $M>0$.

$x_n > M \Rightarrow n(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) > M \Rightarrow n^2(n+1 - 2\sqrt{n^2+n} + n) > M^2 \Rightarrow n^2(2n +1) >M^2$. Since $4n>(2n+1),  \forall n \in \mathbb N$, I can go ahead and writ out:
$n^2.4n>M^2$
$ n> \sqrt[3]{\frac{M^2}{4}}$.
Since I managed to find an "n" for the given $M>0$, it follows that $(x_n)$ is unbounded. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to prove that "if $x_n>M$, then ...", but that is not what you need.

**HINT:**
$$ x_n=n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)= n\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}>n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac12\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in answer to the question, the proposed proof is incorrect.  It suggests that if $n>M^{2/3}4^{-1/3}$, then $x_n>M$.  But looking at Hagen von Eitzen's hint, for $n$ of this size, $x_n$ is approximately $\frac{1}{2} M^{1/3} 4^{-1/6}$, which is less than $M$.